# Redirecting http urls to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There are many example of making all `http` redirects to `https`.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I would like to redirect only those URLs that are coming from a web browsers. As many functions are being used in API calls for mobile applications, hence I can't use the above code as it redirects all urls to https and the APIs calls make the mobile apps crash.

How can I modify the above code, so as to redirect only those URLs thast are coming from a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

To detect web browser again mobile browser you will need to check against `HTTP_ACCEPT` variable.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !(text/vnd\.wap\.wml|application/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml) [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```